# C++: Why we cannot call private destructor on a local variable?

Tags: c++, object, local, destructor, private

when a class has private destructor, only dynamic objects of that class can be created. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a local variable goes out of scope there is an implicit destructor call.

If the destructor is not accessible from that scope, it can't be called.

Comment: #include <iostream>

using namespace std;
 
class Test
{
private:
   ~Test() {}
};
int main()
{ 
   Test *t = new Test;
   delete t;
}
This program fails to compile. 
If i want to delete an object(local variable) before it's function completes the exec then?

Comment: @0726: You can't.  The destructor is like any member function: if it's private, then only a member of that class (or a member of a friend class) can call it.  Period.  Typically, such a class with a private destructor would have some other method to delete the object, or at least to mark it as no longer in use for some kind of garbage collection mechanism.

Comment: I'm not sure what part of this is not obvious to you. If the destructor is not accessible then you can't destroy the object. If destruction would happen automatically for a local variable in a context where the destructor is not accessible, you can't use it as a local variable. If destruction would happen because you delete it in a context where the destructor is not accessible, then you can't delete it.